# CC.NET Dashboard Error: Could not load type 'System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection.ChannelBinding'

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Late last week I upgraded CC.NET locally and on the build server. The build server is still fine, but locally I am now getting the following error:

Exception Details: Exortech.NetReflector.NetReflectorTypeLoadException: Unable to load types from assembly System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089:
Failed to load 1 of the 3612 types defined in the assembly.
Exceptions:
- Unable to load type: System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection.ChannelBinding
Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection.ChannelBinding' from assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I'm afraid this started after a batch of Windows updates this morning. I had another two updates that won't run, 979909 and 982168 (I had an update that wouldn't run last month).

Anyone else having any issues? Thanks!

Edit: I can connect through CCTray and CCNET is running properly. I just can't get to the Dashboard.

> EDIT. Thanks to both of you. I uninstalled
>   everything you both suggested and
>   turned off Windows Update per our IT dept. It didn't
>   work yesterday after a reboot, but
>   after a night of rest and another
>   reboot, it seems to be working now.

Comment: What version of CC.NET are you using?

Comment: 1.5.7256.1 - should be the latest build

Comment: According to this post http://bit.ly/c0Bgd4, v1.6 might solve the problem.

Comment: No help, but I cross-posted to this list, so thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same exception this morning, seemingly out of nowhere.

Turns out some Windows updates were installed over the weekend. After uninstalling the KB976765 and KB979909 updates, the problem went away.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had something to do with the updates. I have three of them that just keep cycling but never complete. I'm going to try an uninstall on them, even though Windows Updates doesn't think they are really installed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the update KB976769v2. It can be fixed as detailed in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2262911/en-us).

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. For us we had to uninstall KB976769v2 in order for the application to work again.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that one. I thought I had uninstalled all the .NET FW updates that were installed over the weekend, but I missed this one. I'm about ready to start with a new image. I am spending way too much time on this. :)